Movie where kids exchange their mom at a carnival
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie where a group of kids end up trading their mom for a different mom (or maybe they were orphans?) at something that looked like a carnival.  Each kid got 1-2 coins to try different mothers.  They end up getting different women that they don't care for, and run out of coins.
At the end of the movie they end up imagining a new mom, and she somehow comes to life.  
I remember seeing it on tv, it may not have had a theatrical release.  I think I saw it around early to mid 90's.
Does anyone recognize this movie?

I did a quick search and the only thing different about my suggestion is the carnival, where here it described as a market, and the final mom they settle on is their own. See Trading Mom at IMDB.
Here's an excerpt of the plot summary:

Elizabeth, Jeremy, and Harry Martin have had it with their workaholic, nagging mother and they get in trouble at school with bullies and almost smoking cigarettes. They go to this mysterious gardener named Mrs. Cavour and she tells the siblings about an ancient spell to make their mother disappear... Mrs. Cavour tells the children about the Mommy Market...had a policy where you could have 3 tokens to take a mother home... The mothers they pick are not what they hoped for and they... must think of a memory of their own to remember her and break the spell.

